Difficulties producing a colorized point cloud for QGIS
For some project, I am trying to colorize a point cloud using the orthophoto from the same coordinates.
I followed various tutorials, and using cloudcompare, i managed to produce a colorized point cloud inside the software.
However, I can't for the life of me transfer it back to QGIS. When saving the point cloud to the recommended .las version 1.4 with points format 7 (to preserve rgb) I get hit by a
[11:47:22] An error occurred while saving 'C:/Users/user/Documents/LHD_FXX_1223_6077_PTS_O_LAMB93_IGN69.copc.las': the third-party library in charge of saving/loading the file has failed to perform the operation
And using a lower format version loses the rgb values. The classification is preserved, but when I change the display to RGB in QGIS I cannot recover the photo colors.
What can I do?
EDIT
This is actually a problem with lasZip:https://github.com/LASzip/LASzip/issues/50
The solution for me was to downgrade to las 1.2 with point format 3 to preserve rgb.
EDIT 2:
Actually it's fine. Qgis just took a loooooog time to load the points and their info. Coffee break saved me
I now manage to output a point cloud bearing rgb values, and i can both render them in lasview and check the existence of the rbg values in lasinfo (the lastool suite)
.\lasinfo.exe -i "C:\merged.copc.las"
reporting all LAS header entries:
  file signature:             'LASF'
  file source ID:             0
  global_encoding:            16
  project ID GUID data 1-4:   00000000-0000-0000-0000-000000000000
  version major.minor:        1.2
  system identifier:          ''
  generating software:        'LASzip DLL 3.4 r3 (191111)'
  file creation day/year:     352/2024
  header size:                227
  offset to point data:       1176
  number var. length records: 2
  point data format:          3
  point data record length:   34
Color R 6912 65280
        G 9216 65280
        B 8448 65280



However, qgis still isn't happy about it and won't render it correctly. Actually, checking the stats from qgis tells me the rgb values are nan! Is there a way to set them correctly to what qgis expects?

good that you found a solution for your question! You can actually copy-paster your "edit" in an answer and check it as resolved - this will help others with the same issue and also solve this question as marked so nobody comes to check, what is the issue here

just a little more: it's slightly more precise, but now qgis doesn't render it colorized when lasview and cloucompare does;;;

so i found a workaround, but it's not really solved per se. It's maybe worth to leave this question open
